# associativity of chow quotients

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For a reductive group $G$ acting on a projective variety $X$, the Chow quotient $X//G$ is defined as follows. Let $U\subseteq X$ be a sufficiently small open subset of $X$ with the property that the homology class of $\overline{G.x}$ is independent of $x\in U$. Then we have a morphism $U\to Chaw(X)$ sending a point to its orbit closure. We define $X//G$ to be the closure of the image of this map (maybe one needs to assume here that $X$ is smooth but im not sure).

Question: Let $H\times G$ acts on a projective variety $X$ and assume if necessary that $X//G$ and $X//H$ are smooth. Is it true that $(X//G)//H\cong X//(G\times H)$? This question comes from my attempt to understant the Gelfand MacPherson correspondence as expained by Kapranov in 
https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9210002 
in a more systematic way, by using this hypothetical identity to the action of a product of a torus and $GL_k$ on the projectivization of the space of $n\times k$ matrices.